# Is there any way I can Optimise my linq query to reduce database calls?

Tags: c#, database, linq, query-optimization

So I have an scenario where I have an Opportunity table that has customer reference and customer Id.
And Customer table that has reference to ProjectManager's table.
Now, I have opportunityId and using that id I need to get Project Manager's information.
Below is my working code,

```cs
public async Task<Object> GetProjectManagerIdAgainstCustomer(int? opportunityId)
{
    var customerId = await _context.Opportunities
        .Where(Opportunity => Opportunity.Id == opportunityId)
        .Include(Opp => Opp.Customer)
        .Select(Opp => Opp.CustomerId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var ProjectManager = await _context.Customers
        .Where(Customer => Customer.Id == customerId)
        .Include(Customer => Customer.ProjectManager)
        .Select(x => new {
            email = x.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerEmail,
            fullname = x.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerName,
        })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return (ProjectManager);
}
```

Now, one of my issues is that these two queries make two trips to the database, which takes me to the main aim of the question, how to optimise it so that all of this is done within one trip and if you guys can find any other issues with this code, that would be great?
Additionaly having any related documentation would help alot.
Secondly, is there any way I could have gotten the ProjectManager object within the attached Customer object, for eg. by using include?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for a join operation.
Try the one documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Using this you can create a join query that will be executed on your database and you will only receive the final output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have navigation property `Opportunities` for `Customer`.

```cs
public async Task<Object> GetProjectManagerIdAgainstCustomer(int? opportunityId)
{
    var query = 
        from c in _context.Customers
        from o in c.Opportunities
        where o.Id == opportunityId
        select new
        {
            email = c.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerEmail,
            fullname = c.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerName,
        }

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Method chain syntax

```cs
public async Task<Object> GetProjectManagerIdAgainstCustomer(int? opportunityId)
{
    var query = _context.Customers
        .SelectMany(c => c.Opportunities.Where(o => o.Id == opportunityId, (c, o) => c)
        .Select(c => new
        {
            email = c.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerEmail,
            fullname = c.ProjectManager.ProjectManagerName,
        });

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thing is I have to use lambdas, to be consistent with our overall implementation.

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: Added. To be good in LINQ to Entities - better to use query syntax.

Comment: I actually didn't have resharper installed, thanks for reminding.